# Open popup window with client template in kendo ui razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I am using kendo grid to display data and i want to open popup window when user click on one of the column having string. my code is

```
columns.Bound(c => c.ResumeFileUrl).EditorViewData(new { PartNo = "#: PartNo #" }).EditorTemplateName("ResumeFileUrlEditor").ClientTemplate("<a href='"  + "/#=Id#'>View Details</a>");
```

and my jquery is:

```
$("#mId").click(function () {
    $("#Proposal").data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```

and my Kendo window is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("Proposal")
    .Title("Proposal")
    .Iframe(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
)
```

when i click on column string the popup window is not opening. what is wrong with the code ??

Comment: are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: No, am not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your client template to this:

```
"<a href='\\\\#' data-id='#=Id#'>View Details</a>"
```

This will print a link like: `<a href='#' data-id='1'>View Details</a>`. Then change your jQuery to this:

```
$("[data-id]").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // Here's the Id of the item which user have clicked
    $("#Proposal").data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```

What is happening?

- The link was set to have no url or a valid anchor(`href="#"`) hence clicking on it won't perform any *visible* action to the user;
- Was added a data attribute the each item called `id`, so you can access it by `.data("id")` with jQuery.

Now inside the click event you have the clicked `id` and you can open your detail view with it.

Comment: it is not working, i am adding it as:  "<a href='\\\\#' data-id='#=PartNo#'>View Details</a>". Should i change anything in the jQuery

Comment: @Acnologia escaping `#` in kendo's template is really a bitch, try `\\#`. In worst case, use `href='javascript:void(0)'` instead.

Comment: @Acnologia describe what you mean with "it is not working". There is a lot of stages in your request that could or could not work. The template renders the *View Details* link ok? If yes, the click event works? If yes, the `id` inside the event is being defined? And so on... help me help you.

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake, now it's working. Thanks for the help @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: @Acnologia good to know!! Now, if the answer helped you achieving your goal, please consider checking it as the question's answer.

Comment: @Acnologia - if you solved it, either update your question with the code that works, answer your own question with the correct answer, or something of that nature - other folks may have the same question and could get some use out of your solution :)